Will running bare wire to this part of the box properly ground my receptacle?
I had an outlet with wiring that did not touch the box itself. Here's what it looks like now.

Here is the spot I hope is designed for a ground screw:

Here is how I want to wire it. Would this work if the screw fits?


Usually ground screws are placed on the back wall of boxes.  If no threaded hole, then can drill and tap(10-32) a hole for a ground screw.  You want six inches of free wire from cable sheath.

If the ground (bare) wire is long enough, you make a loop around the grounding screw in the box, then continue to the outlet. In your case, the bare wire is short. Make a couple pigtails (short pieces of wire): one goes to the box, the other goes to the outlet. Make sure to use a green screw for the box.

OP needs to strip more sheath from the wires.  Should only be around 1/4 inch inside the box.
